# How to manage cables with cabinets

Tags: cabinets, cable-management

We're in the process of installing a wet bar with cabinets and a bar fridge.  Pictured below:

[image: Cabinet setup]

We have the bar fridge going into this middle section and utilizing the other available outlet.  My question for you is - what would a pro do in this scenario to manage the cables?

My first thought would be to drill a square hole on the outside of the left cabinet to fit the plug for the surge protector back through and re-plug into the wall.  I'm not concerned with making a small hole on the side of the cabinet, since it will be concealed by the fridge.

More or less, how would you go about hiding the cable so it's not going around to the front of the cabinet?  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you have budget to add an outlet in the back of the cabinet? A good electrician could almost certainly do it without drywall damage.

Comment: Consider swapping the cabinet and the fridge. One hole in the back of the cabinet for the outlet to remain accessible, one hole in the side for the fridge's cord to come through.

Comment: @FreeMan Looks like the baseboard was cut to fit that gap, so you'd have to move the baseboard as well.  My recommendation is get a power strip with a flat-sitting plug so you can get the fridge as far back as possible and put a 2" hole toward the back of the cabinet and run the cable through there.

Comment: Good spot, @tnknepp. Looks to me like it was cut short of the cabinet on the right, but it _appears_ to me that it runs behind the cabinet on the left. Hard to tell for sure from this angle. Either way, nobody's going to see the baseboard behind cabinets/fridges, so it really doesn't need to be there at all. Though it does give 3/4" or so of clearance for a power plug.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate That's 100% the answer. Write it up and +1.

Comment: The left cabinet already has a hole in the bottom right corner.  Just run the power plug of the power strip out that old to the outlet.  Use a power strip/surge protector with a flat plug.

Comment: Any slide-in unit should already have sufficient space behind to get wiring/plugs behind without impeding anything. EU units are all 600mm deep, but usually have cutaways towards the bottom rear for this. Any other hole-making would only be visible from inside the cupboard to the left - which you can mask with a door. if you wanted to be 'anorak' tidy, chop the plug off & replace after slotting the cable through a amsll drilled hole.

Comment: I like the "cut and shut" plug idea to make a smaller hole, @Tetsujin. Unfortunately, it means the process must be reversed when the surge protector dies. Which they do. Often. Especially if they've been busy doing what they're designed to do.

Comment: @FreeMan - agreed, but I used to spend so much of my life squeezing wires through small holes I got a plug change down to about a minute, even if I had to cut & prep the cable [I do have a cable prep tool, not just a sharp knife]. I've still got an entire supermarket carrier-bag full of spare plugs..

Comment: For better or worse, @Tetsujin, most people aren't you... ;)

Comment: Thank you to all of you for your advice, I really appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a hole saw hole big enough to pass the plug through - round holes are easy, square holes are slow/difficult. Trim optional (it's the back of the cabinet, only your nosy parent-in-law would ever look back there) but available if you want a nicer look for prying eyes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just going to go the route of drilling a hole through the cabinet side, since they're already installed and mounted on the wall.  Spade bits for the win!

Comment: When using a spade bit, start on the side that should look nice. They tend to blow out the back of the hole in a messy fashion.

Comment: You can do the same as you would with an auger or holesaw (when looking for nicer on both sides) and change to the other side as soon as the center point comes through